# Downloading and installing Visual Studio Code Go dependencies

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code and the Go extension on an **offline** computer and now I need to install the dependencies on that computer.
How can I do it please?

Comment: It automatically downloaded and installed, while you starting VS Code or it will show in the VS Code notification with installation guide.

Comment: @logeshpalani98 it won't automatically download anything on an **offline** computer, as the question states.

Comment: just follow this guide https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: If both of your online and offline PCs have the same OS and architecture, simply copy the `$GOPATH` directory and you are good to go.

(Note: Replace all `$GOPATH` with `%GOPATH%` for Windows OS)

---

### Online

Go to the [Go tools that the Go extension depends on](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Go-tools-that-the-Go-extension-depends-on), and follow instructions for your OS:

1. An example for [dlv](https://github.com/go-delve/delve):

```sh
go get -u -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

An example for [The Language Server](https://langserver.org/):

```sh
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gopls
```

That is all.

---

### Offline

2. For the **offline** installation you need first copy these files to the offline computer and just run e.g.:

```sh
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
go install
```

Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all the packages you need, or simply have a clean `GOPATH/src` on first PC then compress all, then copy the compressed file and uncompress it then run `go install` for all packages you need to install.

---

3. [Go Tools](https://github.com/golang/tools/):

#### Online

The easiest way to install is to run:

```sh
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/...
```

#### Offline copy

You can also manually git clone the repository to:
`$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools`

Comment: it doesn't work because for example the dlv `go install` require you to have internet connection (it needs to download  more dependencies)

Comment: go1.13.4 windows/amd64  on the online computer 
on the offline its multiple offline computers with windows 7  and 10.

Comment: The `%GOPATH%\bin` contains all tools the VSCode needs e.g. `%GOPATH%\bin\dlv.exe` and copy that  `%GOPATH%\bin` from online to offline PCs. you only need source only if you need to rebuild or go install it otherwise  `%GOPATH%\bin` is enough.

Comment: If i will do that does'nt that means i will need to move my project from the offline computer to the online one every time i need a new update?

Comment: When you are working on an offline PC, and for a tools update of course you need to repeat this process again. so it is very easy to work in an online PC. also you may automate the copy task and build a Go program to do the copy task. You may connect online and offline PCs using router via different networks e.g. Virtual private network and automate the task completely.

Comment: If you are specifically installing `staticcheck`, there is a separate binary file for Windows vs. Mac, so if you are copying cross-platform make sure you get the right one for your OS.